# Instasharp - Post images/comments

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, instagram

Is it possible to post one image or one comment to instagram with instasharp?

I'm using instasharp for windows phone.

I searched on the forum & internet but doesn't have any solution.

Regards,

Comment: There's a thing called, testing and iteration...you should try it sometime.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/blob/master/src/InstaSharp/Endpoints/Comments.cs

You would instantiate a new Comments object and then call Post() to post a comment.
As mentioned here https://github.com/mislav/instagram/wiki/media posting media is not strictly supported through their API